# Pickadate Timepicker doesn't display correct hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I'm trying to use the datepicker and the timepicker from the [Pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js) plugin.
I don't have a problem with the datepicker, but I have trouble getting the expected output from the Timepicker

I have this HTML code in my page

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker"/>
```

And this jQuery part

```
 var $time_input;
 $time_input = jQuery('.timepicker').pickatime({
    format: 'HH:i',
    formatLabel: 'HH:i',
    interval: 40,
    min: [5,40],
    max: [22,20]
});
```

The timepicker works and I can select time but it doesn't start at 5:40 am. I know it's named min so it doesn't mean it should start at this value but I wonder if someone can help me make it work. 
Basically I want the output to be : 5:40am then 6:20am, 7:00am, etc until the final value 10:20pm. 
But the output I get now is : 5:20am then 6:00am, 6:40am, etc.

I'm not a javascript expert.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer of pickadate.js added a fix for my problem in [3.3.0](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/index.htm)!